# Is it possible to invite others to watch a replay with you?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is it possible to invite others to watch a replay with you on StarCraft 2, haven't found how to do so if it is even possible.

If it's possible, please tell me how to do so.

Comment: It's probably better to setup a live stream [like Day[9] is doing](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/3964130/)

Comment: Easier? Yes.  Better?  Doubtful.  Part of the point of replays is learning, and part of learning is being able to navigate where you want, when you want, in the replay (as well as choosing which stats to show, income, resource, what's building, etc)

Comment: @Matt better than not being able to watch the replay together at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not currently possible.  But a lot of people have been requesting this feature, and caught Blizzards ear.  If/when it actually gets implemented, who knows, but at least there's this:

```
This is a functionality we're interested in providing our players at some point in the future. :)
```

http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/189279348#7

Answer (score 1):

You can load the same replay with your friend and start at the same moment and chat.
I often do it with my practice partners after the game.

Comment: That’s what I did too. Glad to see I’m not the only retard who thought about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, inviting others to watch replays is not possible inside StarCraft 2.  However, Blizzard posts on their forums have indicated they desire to get this feature in via a patch in the future. I don't believe there is an ETA or any sort of official announcement about it.